# Python taking a bit long and weird?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python.
Again, uh..I apologize for the noobnes.

so, I have the following script
Basically I'm trying to learn by making projects, for example a .py that changes your wallpaper, plays a creepy sound and shows a 'message box'. and it repeats for 3 times.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes as w
from playsound import playsound
count = 0
while (count < 3): 
 count = count + 1
 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
 ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "horror.jpg" , 0)
 user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
 MessageBox = user32.MessageBoxW
 MessageBox.argtypes = w.HWND,w.LPCWSTR,w.LPCWSTR,w.UINT
 MessageBox.restype = ctypes.c_int
 MessageBox(None, u'works 3 times', u'test:', 0)
 playsound('cursed.mp3')
```

my question would be : why is it working so slow or what am I doing wrong ?
For example, it firsts changes the wallpaper and shows the notification...after I click ok it plays the sound :/
Then it repeats...but it takes like 2 seconds in-between-commands...if that makes sense...I apologise for the extreme stupid question, but I would like some clarification...Have I skipped the 'syntax' class ?

Comment: When you say 2 second, you mean for each iteration? What is the duration/length of `cursed.mp3`?

Comment: 2 seconds :/ and I dont know why it also waits 2 seconds before executing each 'command'